# How to forward command into run-commands using NX CLI?

Tags: nrwl-nx, nrwl, nx.dev

Given I have entries in angular.json that define various commands using the serverless CLI (as an example)

```
"serverless-deploy": {
  "builder": "@nrwl/workspace:run-commands",
  "options": {
    "command": "npx serverless deploy",
    "cwd": "apps/my-app"
  }
},
"serverless-remove": {
  "builder": "@nrwl/workspace:run-commands",
  "options": {
    "command": "npx serverless remove",
    "cwd": "apps/my-app"
  }
}
```

How can I improve this by reducing duplication and combining it into one entry so that I can forward the command in?

E.G something like this:

```
"sls": {
  "builder": "@nrwl/workspace:run-commands",
  "options": {
    "command": "npx serverless",
    "cwd": "apps/my-app"
  }
}
```

And then call it with nx run my-app:sls MYCOMMAND (E.G 'deploy' or 'remove')?
Unfortunately the above doesn't work but would love to know if this is possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
"sls": {
  "builder": "@nrwl/workspace:run-commands",
  "options": {
    "commands": [
      "npx sls {args.cmd}"
    ],
    "cwd": "apps/api",
    "parallel": false
  }
},

nx run api:sls --cmd=deploy
```